# How to ping a VM on different network & region from a GCE VM with multiple network interfaces(Qwik Labs)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, vpc

This is regards to Qwiklabs "Multiple VPC Networks" and last section "Explore the network interface connectivity"

In the last part, i have created a VM(vm-appliance) in region us-central1 and zone us-central1-c with 4vCPUs with multiple interfaces,

1. Network privatenet(custom) using subnetwork privatesubnet-us - nic0
2. Network managementnet(custom) using managementsubnet-us - nic1
3. Network mynetwork(auto) using mynetwork -nic2

From the vm-applicance not able to ping internal ip of mynet-eu-vm as its in mynetwork network and default network interface(nic0) which is privatenet, a different network so not able to access mynet-eu-vm.

Full text from lab,

> The primary interface eth0 gets the default route (default via
>   172.16.0.1 dev eth0), and all three interfaces eth0, eth1 and eth2 get routes for their respective subnets. Since, the subnet of mynet-eu-vm
>   (10.132.0.0/20) is not included in this routing table, the ping to
>   that instance leaves vm-appliance on eth0 (which is on a different VPC
>   network). You could change this behavior by configuring policy routing
>   as documented here.

End of the lab they left saying "You could change this behavior by configuring policy routing as documented"
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces#configuring_policy_routing

It would be good to know, how to connect to mynet-eu-vm

Comment: Provided that the networks do not overlap, you can use VPC Network Peering to connect the two private networks together. https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering

Comment: Thanks John. I will look into VPC Peering